# It does not appear to be a valid archive (Byte array to zip file in c#.net)

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I am facing issue while converting byte array to zip file.Even though zip file is created using the below code but when I am extracting the zip file I am getting error `"Cannot open file. It does not appear to be a valid archive"`.

```
private static void ShowZipFile(string fileName, byte[] data)
{
    byte[] compress = Compress(data);
    File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, compress);
}            

private static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(memory,
        CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            gzip.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        return memory.ToArray();
    } 

}
```

Comment: How are you extracting the zip file?  Are you doing it programmatically, or using an external utility like 7zip?  If you're doing it programmatically, what's the code you're using to do that?

Comment: No..I am extracting it manually.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "extracting it manually"?  You need to be a LOT more specific than that

Comment: I just right clicking on the zip file and clicking on extract here.

Comment: I have byte array to which I have to convert in file either it is excel file or zip file or any other file. This code is converting the byte array in file but I am only able to open excel file not the zip file.

Answer (score 2):

A `GZipStream` isn't a zip file, basically - it's a gzip file. That's just compressed data, without any notions of multiple files, file names etc. If you save the file as `foo.gz` you may find that the zip tool you use knows how to decompress that, but you definitely need to understand that it's not the same as a `foo.zip` with file entries etc.

If you want to create an *actual* zip file, you might want to look at [SharpZipLib](https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/), [`System.IO.Compression.ZipFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile) or similar libraries.

Comment: I am not getting this namespace System.IO.Compression.zipFile in .net 4.5

Comment: @user3206357: Well do you have a reference to System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll?

Comment: yes..There is reference of System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

Comment: @user3206357: Well I can't tell what you're doing wrong, other than that the type is `ZipFile` with a capital `z`. I've just tried this with a new project targeting .NET 4.5, and it found the type with no problems. Note that it's the name of a *type*, not a *namespace*.

Comment: Skeet Can you please share the code which is using ZipFile?

Comment: As Jon said, have your tried saving your original file as `.gz` rather than `.zip` and opening it?  While it might not be what you want that would at least confirm that it's just an issue of using a mismatched file format and extension.

Comment: @user3206357: Well there's sample code in the documentation, for one thing. It may be that `ZipFile` is too high-level for you, in which case look at SharpZipLib or something similar.

Comment: Yes..I tried this as well but when I am extracting this file I am getting file without any extension as I expect a folder with 2 files and images within it but I am getting a file without any extension.

Comment: @user3206357: I don't know what you mean by that comment... but I've explained why the code you've got will *not* save a valid zip file.

Comment: I was just explaining that I have tried many things but could not find any solution.